# How to manipulate registrations from a single point in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I was using Castle Windsor to manipulate registrations. For instance, Windsor's Kernal has an event, named ComponentRegistered, where I can register to that event and add an interceptor to the service if given service/component has a specific attribute. Example:

```
handler.ComponentModel
       .Interceptors.Add(new InterceptorReference(typeof(UnitOfWorkInterceptor)));
```

I can do that conditional by checking handler.ComponentModel.Implementation type.

I'm looking a similar hook in Autofac but could not find it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing using `Module` and the `AttachToComponentRegistration` method. This method will be fired for each registration (present and future).

```
public class InterceptorModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Activating += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Component.Services.Any<IService>())
            {
                e.ReplaceInstance(...);
            }
        };
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    }
}
```

You will have to register this module in *Autofac* like this :

```
builder.RegisterModule(new InterceptorModule());
```

You can also use the native castle plugin :

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>()
       .As<ISomeInterface>()
       .EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
builder.Register(c => new CallLogger(Console.Out));
var container = builder.Build();
var willBeIntercepted = container.Resolve<ISomeInterface>();
```

See [Interceptors](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) from the *Autofac* documentation for more information

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't want to use it on service registration to not repeat adding interceptors for every service. I want to make it by convention for specific interfaces. So, first solution seems a good workaround, however it would be better to have more oppurtunity than just replacing instance. It would be good to have same registration API in a central place.

Comment: @hikalkan I'm not sure to understand what you want. You can do everything you want in Module. Could you explain what is missing ?

Comment: I want to intercept classes (with dynamic class proxy interception). I don't want to do that on builder.Register... because I have a convention: If a service implements a specific interface or has a specific attribute, it should be automatically intercepted regardless it's registered with EnableInterfaceInterceptors or InterceptedBy methods. So, how I can implement this convention?

Comment: I never used castle *Autofac*'s plugin because I always have custom logic implemented using *Autofac* module. *Autofac* module could do everything you could do using a `ContainerBuilder` In my sample, I listen to the `Activating` event and then replace the instance using the `ReplaceInstance` but you could do everything you want.

Comment: Thank you. But you can not create a dynamic proxy for class services (a service which is registered by self, not over an interface). Because class proxies use inheritance (Castle creates a new class Castle.DynamicProxy.YourClassProxy which derives from YourClass) and you can not proxy a target object without providing ctor arguments (unless it has a default constructor).

Comment: Anyway, your suggestion solves most of cases, but mine is more complicated and requires to registration API. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @hikalkan What do you mean by "requires to registration API" ? do you need to add new registration ? in such case you can use `componentRegistry` which have method to have new registration

Comment: No, to manipulate existing registrations. Think that, as a last step, before creating the Container I want to get all registations, and for each registration I want to make additional configuration. Say that I want to call .EnableInterfaceInterceptors() for each registration. As I checked source code of Automapper, this is not possible.